# How to hide Logon Password in Teradata MLoad Script

Tags: teradata, mload

I have written a Multiload script to Load Data in TeraData Database and the commands in the script is like:

```
.LOGTABLE Employee_log;  
.LOGON 192.168.1.1/dbc,dbc; 
.BEGIN MLOAD TABLES Employee_Stg;  
.LAYOUT Employee;  
.FIELD in_EmployeeNo * VARCHAR(10);  
.FIELD in_FirstName * VARCHAR(30); ....
```

But the password is clearly visible in the script. Is there a option to secure the password or any alternate way/command to logon and then run the script.

Comment: [Teradata Wallet](http://downloads.teradata.com/download/tools/teradata-wallet-for-windows) is intended for this purpose, I believe, although I've never used it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a logon file and run it in your MLOAD script using the following command
`.RUN FILE logonfile.txt`

In the logon file you can provide the statement that you used in your script    `.LOGON 192.168.1.1/dbc,dbc;`

Comment: But still The password is getting stored in the text file. If you are in a prod system and executing this file there are great chances of security breach. So I asked is there any other way to directly execute logon command and then execute this script.

Comment: You can restrict access to the directory where the logon file is stored.. that's how we are doing in our production system..

Comment: You may put the tdwallet string into your logon-file. Thus, even if a user has access to the logon-file, he can't use it e.g. on his local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Restrict access to logonfile.txt, though only the user can read it

```
chmod go-rwx logonfile.txt
```

or use tdwallet

```
.LOGON 192.168.1.1/dbc,$tdwallet(dbc)
```

tdwallet keeps the entries safely away, only access via logon command. 
There is no function to get an entry in cleartext.

Comment: My Load file is getting generated by a Java Program. Also I need to put the password in tdwallet using the same/diff Java Program. But when I tried adding an item in tdwallet using Java, it did not ran. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Adding an entry (password) to tdwallet is done via command line `tdwallet add` and it is then asking for terminal input. You can't  use a pipe or a parameter for the password input. Only option would be `expect` (don`t know about a java equivalent for that).